# How to capture customer replies in Salesforce

Tags: email, apex-email-service

We want to log outbound and inbound emails in Salesforce. Currently, We are sending Emails to Contacts using out of the box salesforce features and they re getting logged But when contacts reply to the sent emails they are not getting logged. I also wrote on Email service but Still emails are not getting captured.

However when i manually test the Email service using the email address generated by Email Service they are getting logged properly .

[image]

do we need set the address generated by email service while we send email in BCC field?

Or any other setting that we need to do?